# What is the significances of the phrase "Fish, Cookie, Weasel"?

Tags: rick-riordan, the-kane-chronicles

At the end of *The Throne of Fire* by Rick Riordan, Ra states "Fish, Cookie, Weasel" in his sleep. Weasel is mentioned in the book earlier, and that meaning is known, but what about Cookie and Fish? They seem to be mentioned a lot as well. What significance do they have?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

cookie=Carter, Weasel=Walt, Zebras=Zia. What is Fish? We already have these possibilities:

Fish=Felix (first letter),
Fish=Sadie (in relation to Isis), Fish=Isis (sound similar, i guess),
Fish=Bast (cats eat fish),
Fish=Set (fish is a common symbol of Set),

I have come up with one more:

Fish=Rem;
He hasn't been mentioned in the story yet, but Rem is the Egyptian god of fish. I guess that it's possible he could be featured in a future book.

Comment: Not so sure about the cookie/Carter thing. Ra might have just liked cookies. (consider the "weasel cookie" request)

Answer (score 2):

Well, Weasel is clearly Walt, known by the fact that Ra says 'Weasels are sick.' He also mentions Zebras, which can be assumed means Zia. If both of these are true, it is possible they have something to do with characters who's names start with that letter. The only character I could find who's name starts with F (for fish) is Felix. And there are only two for C (for cookie); Carter and Cleo, though Carter seems more likely. If it has nothing to do with their names, well... then I have no clue. :)

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so towards the end of the throne of fire, we learn for a fact that Zebras: Zia, and that Weasles: Walt. Cookie is most likely Carter, but could be Desjardins, because Ra told Menshikov/Apophis that "Cookie is coming" and then Desjardins came at Menshikov/Apophis. However, it is more likely that Cookie is Carter because just like Zia and Walt, the first letter of Cookie and Carter match up. And then there's the one that stumps me: Fish. Possibly Felix? It might be Sadie, but the first letter of the name thing dosent fit in. Bast or maybe Set or Irish? I doubt it. I guess we just need to line things up to figure it out. Then Moonpies: Khonsu. He's the good of the moon, so yeah. Hope this was helpful!

Answer (score 0):

It seems very likely that these are character names. As Amanda mentioned, Zia= Zebras, Weasel= Walt, Cookie is probably Carter. The big question is then, who is Fish?

There are a few possibilities that I see.

Fish could be Bast, a reference to the fact that cats like to eat fish.

Sadie is a possibility, although I can't for the life of me figure out how Sadie could be related to Fish, in name or other traits. Still, she seems to be the only major character that would relate to her, so it seems unlikely. It is at least remotely possible that it could be due to similarities to the word Isis.

[Set](http://ablemedia.com/ctcweb/consortium/ancientegyptiangodsseth.html) is known to have the symbol of a fish, which could be some kind of a clue to pointing towards one who channels Set.

Bottom line is, it's never really explained who or what Fish is. Perhaps a future story will give more clues.